# Data is not showing. Ng-reflect-ng-for-off:null?

Tags: angular, angularfire, angularfire2

Hi i am trying to bind a data from firebase. And I'm not getting errors but data is not showing. In inspect element i'm getting

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->
```

My *app.component.html* is

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my *app.component.ts* is

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFirestore } from "angularfire2/firestore";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2";


@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {}
}
```

if app.module.ts is needed i can add it. So the thing is how to get rid of that ng-reflect thing and show my data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-reflect-ng-for-of` comment is binding information for Angular. Those comments will still exist, even in production, though they may be empty there.

Are you excluding code from your `app.component.ts` in your post?

Your issue is probably caused by the `items` property not being set in your component. Since you're using the `async` pipe, you are implying that you are expecting `items` to be an observable. Try setting your `items` property as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = "app";
    items: Observable<{title: string}>;

    constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.items = db.collection<{title: string}>('items').valueChanges();
    }
}
```

More information can be found in the [Angular Firestore documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/14e78ec6d3c51a8d82db1308c340ee23c7cb7b83/docs/firestore/collections.md#using-angularfirestorecollection).